# Assert in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, assert, string-comparison

I am trying to assert two strings. But even though the strings are same, the test case fails. Following is what I have written:

```
String actualmsg="My expected string";
String errormsg = driver.findelement(By.xpath("xpath of the element")).getText();
Assert.assertEquals(actualmsg, errormsg);
```

When I print errormsg on console, it gives same string as actualmsg. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the **exactly** the same? no trailing or leading white spaces in each of them? "My expected string" and "My expected string " are not the same. So as "My expected string" and "my expected string"

Comment: I think the asserting is not of Selenium but of JUnit or TestNG or other testing frameworks (you might want to specify which one you are using). Regardless, if you are sure the strings are equal there might be some leading or trailing space you cannot see in the console. Try `Assert.assertEquals(actualmsg.trim(), errormsg.trim());`

Comment: Can you share logs/debug messages to ascertain both strings are same. Also do share details of framework for which "Assert" class belongs.

Answer (score 0):

use Hamcrest assertion to compare you will get the result in the exception is not matching.

You use:

assertThat(actualmsg, is(errormsg));